# administrate custom action on show page

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-administrate, administrate

I would like to add a reinvite user button on my users show page.

My reinvite button looks like this:

```
    def reinvite
        User.reinvite!
    end
```

And the button looks like this:

```
    <%= link_to(
  "Reinvite User",
  [namespace, page.resource],
  class: "button",
  ) if valid_action?(:reinvite) && show_action?(:reinvite, 
  page.resource) %>
```

But the button don't render on the show page.

Comment: How are `valid_action?` and `show_action?` defined? What is `page.resource`? Is there a user currently logged in?

Comment: I found the solution, I had to define a route for my action as suggested [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/issues/222)